# Calculate the gradient of a function that is written with abstract vectors

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis

:)

I am supposed to calculate the gradient of the following function:

$$f(\mathbf{w})=\sum^{n}_{i=0}\log(1+\exp(-y_i\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i))+\frac{1}{b}\sum^{n}_{i=0}w_i^4$$

Where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $b$ some (real) constant $>0$ and $w_i$ denotes the i-th coordinate of the paramter $\mathbf{w}$.

Now, let's start with the second part, because it's easy:

$$\nabla \frac{1}{b}\sum^{n}_{i=0}w_i^4 = \frac{4}{b}\sum^{n}_{i=0}w_i^3$$

Using basic calculus. For the other part, I would just use the chain rule, differentiating $\log$ first, $\exp$ then etc. However, its the first time I have to do something like this using vector notation. I don't know how to "pull out" or use the $\mathbf{x}$ as inner differative.

Is it: $$\nabla \sum^{n}_{i=0}\log(1+\exp(-y_i\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i)) =  \sum^{n}_{i=0} (1+\exp(-y_i\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i))^{-1} \cdot \exp(-y_i\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i) \cdot -y_i\mathbf{x}_xi  $$

?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ are just columns of the full data matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$.

For convenience, define two new variable 
$$\eqalign{
 z &= X^Tw \cr
dz &= X^Tdw \cr\cr
 e &= \exp(-y\circ z) \cr
de &= -e\circ y\circ dz \cr
}$$
where $\circ$ denotes the elementwise (aka Hadamard) product.

Now write the function in terms of these new variables and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= 1:\Big(\log(1+e)+\frac{w^{\circ 4}}{b}\Big) \cr
df &= 1:\Big(\frac{de}{1+e}+\frac{4w^{\circ 3}\circ dw}{b}\Big) \cr
   &= 1:\Big(-\frac{e\circ y\circ dz}{1+e}+\frac{4w^{\circ 3}\circ dw}{b}\Big) \cr
   &= \frac{-e\circ y}{1+e}:dz+\frac{4w^{\circ 3}}{b}:dw \cr
   &= \frac{-e\circ y}{1+e}:X^Tdw+\frac{4w^{\circ 3}}{b}:dw \cr
   &= \frac{4w^{\circ 3}}{b}:dw-X\Big(\frac{e\circ y}{1+e}\Big):dw \cr
}$$
In the above,

- a colon denotes the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product),
- $w^{\circ 3}$ denote an elementwise (aka Hadamard) power,
- and $\frac{y}{z}$ denotes the elementwise (Hadamard) division of the vector $y$ by the vector $z$.

Anyway, since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}:dw\big),\,$ the gradient can be identified from that last line as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= \frac{4w^{\circ 3}}{b}-X\Big(\frac{e\circ y}{1+e}\Big)
}$$